# SonarQube scan for multiple Gradle Java projects having separate git repository

Tags: java, git, gradle, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have 3 *Gradle* java projects having separate repositories in *GIT*.

Now I want to do code analysis of all these three projects in single go through *SonarQube*.

Scan report should get generated under one project only on *SonarQube* dashboard.

I tried to implement it by assigning multiple values (source folder of each project) to

```
sonar.source = src, Proj2/src, Proj3/src
```

in **gradle.property** file of first project.

But it is not scanning all the project's source folder only first project is getting scan where I have defined *sonar* properties and *sonarqube* Gradle task.

Comment: Did you read [Analyzing with SonarQube Scanner for Gradle](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Gradle)?

Comment: Yes, I have gone through it. Here, implementation for Sonar scan for sub-projects of a main Gradle project is given. But in our case there is no sub project, all the projects are individual Gradle projects and having separate repositories in GitHub